# Inline Lambda Expression in Watch Window

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, watch-window

I usually need to write custom lambda expressions during debugging.

As an example:

`(new Func<int, string>(x => $"{commandParameters[x].ParameterName} : {commandParameters[x].Value}"))(2)`

or a shorter one:

`(new Func<int, string>(x => x.ToString()))(2)`

or

`((Func<int, string>)(x => x.ToString()))(2)`

I'd like to know the simplest form that we can write such expressions so that they can be evaluated in `Watch` window.

Omitting the `Func` construction we would have `(x => x.ToString())(2)` which is much more readable but it won't be evaulated due to `CS0149: Method name expected`

Lovely Candidates:

- `(x => x.ToString())(2)`
- `((int x) => x.ToString())(2)`

Comment: How about a type cast, instead of `new`? `(Func<int, string>)(x => x.ToString())(2)`

Comment: @ZevSpitz, I already added it in edited question, it's simpler but yet we have to specify the func type

Comment: What is the purpose of the lambda expression if you are hardcoding the parameter? Why not just say `2.ToString()`?

Comment: @NetMage, look at the first example where the parameter is used in a complex expression and multiple places

Comment: And yet `$"{commandParameters[2].ParameterName} : {commandParameters[2].Value}"` still seems feasible, especially since this is for debugging.

Comment: @NetMage it's just a simple example, one can have more complex queries to be evaluated during runtime, then how many times he/she should repeat and change the input values?